# Adding lightbox to tumblr doesn´t work

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I´ve tried lightbox, fancybox, etc but none of these lightbox function on my theme.

This is the one I´m using: http://vintage.themelantic.com/

And I wanted to make a "zoom" icon (wich I did) that when you click on it you can see the post image in a lightbox like here ---> http://narniatheme.tumblr.com/

I added all the codes correctly but still doesn´t work, it just loads the image on a new page. Anyone knows how I may be able to do this?

The only thing I was able to add was the "zoom" icon.

---

I took the codes from the code of "Narnia theme" but when I tried adding lightbox from 0 it didn´t work either. I searched the whole code to see if I missed something, I think I didn´t but maybe I did jaja If I can add the ones from the Narnia theme it would be awesome. I placed them exactly in the order and place they had originally but on Vintage theme.

Here is Vintage theme code just in case: pastebin.com/embed_js/gz5s56T7

```
---->I added below <head>: <-------------

<meta name="if:Lightbox" content="1"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/ssdtkch/AhIlqr0kb/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/ssdtkch/YP9ls3323/untitled.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://static.tumblr.com/ssdtkch/EUjlqtc4s/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />


---> Below </style><-------------

{block:iflightbox}
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
/* This is basic - uses default settings */
$("a#single_image").fancybox();
/* Using custom settings */
$("a#inline").fancybox({
'hideOnContentClick': true
});


$("#various3").fancybox({
        'width' : '50%',
        'height'        : '30%',
        'autoScale'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'type'  : 'iframe'
        });
});
</script>

{/block:iflightbox}


---- >Code for the posts:<-------------

{block:iflightbox}
<a id="single_image" href="{PhotoURL-500}" ><img src="http://27.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lqr0e7QyrS1r0kskpo1_100.png" style="margin-left:3px; border:0px; width:24px; height:20px;cursor:pointer; float:left;" class="reblog_etc" alt=""/></a>


{/block:iflightbox}
```

Comment: Could you please add some of the code you added? What parts of the "zoom" code have you pasted in your Tumblr theme?

Comment: @JonasZaugg I edited my post and added the codes I used!

Comment: @JonasZaugg added the original code of Vintage theme also!

Comment: Thanks for the code! I'm sure I can help you (having tinkered my fair share of themes) but I'll only be back on my laptop tomorrow.

Comment: @JonasZaugg That´s perfect, thank you so much for your help :) and don´t worry I´m not in a hurry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've looked at your code and nothing worked. So I looked at your sources, figured out what you'd done and what you wanted and it's working now. Before I show you how to fix it, please be extra careful when copying scripts and css from different themes without looking at how they interact (or you might get very unexpected results).

So what happened is that you copied some scripts from various sources and they expected other scripts to be there so they crashed (resulting in your anchor tag being just a link to a photo in a new tab).

Please do the following :

1. Erase the whole HTML theme, paste the original Vintage theme again (let's start from scratch)
2. Around line 96 you'll have a `<!-- CSS-->` HTML comment (or search for it). Paste the following just on the next line :

   ```
   <!-- Lightbox-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.css">
   <meta name="if:Lightbox" content="1">
   ```

   This will add the Fancybox library's CSS from an open source (it's easier than uploading the file to tumblr), upon which your lightbox is based.
3. Search for `<!-- Thumbnail Hover-->`. That's the black pane appearing when you hover on the picture. You'll see a `<div class="thumb-icons">` there, containing the Reblog and Like buttons. After these two, but still inside the `thumb-icons` div, add :

   ```
   <!-- Lightbox-->
   {block:iflightbox}
   {block:Photo}
   <div class="thumb-icon">
       <a class="fancybox" href="{PhotoURL-500}" ><img src="http://27.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lqr0e7QyrS1r0kskpo1_100.png" style="margin-left:3px; border:0px; width:24px; height:20px;cursor:pointer; float:left;" class="reblog_etc" alt=""/></a>
   </div>{/block:Photo}
   {/block:iflightbox}
   ```

   This will add your zoom icon on all Photos (not photosets though) when you hover on them.
4. Search for `<!-- Javascript-->`. Amidst these scripts, **but after the three first (jquery.min.js, jquery.infinitescroll.js and vintage.js)**, add :

   ```
   <!-- Lightbox-->
   {block:iflightbox}
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".fancybox").fancybox();
   });
   </script>
   {/block:iflightbox}
   ```

   This will import the Fancybox script and initialize it (which wasn't happening in your code).
5. Final step : update the preview, save the theme and toggle the "Lightbox" setting in your theme preferences (where you might have to edit your colors again I'm afraid), maybe off and on. Update the preview and check that the zoom icon is there and that the magic happens when you click.

There's of cours a lot you can edit and customize now but I think it's easiest if you refer to Fancybox's official page : http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Please tell me if it works now and have a great day!

Comment: Hi Jonas! First of all thank you so much for your help and for taking the time to explain this so carefully!
For some reason it´s not working! I placed everything exactly as you said and put the theme exactly as it was. Here is my testing blog for you to see: http://ltamobile.tumblr.com/
The icon appears but fancybox doesn´t work, it just opens the image normally. I toggled the "lightbox" setting on and off multiple times, now is "on".

Is there maybe something missing?

Comment: So sorry, I stuffed up! I corrected step number 4 (jquery wasn't declared so fancybox wouldn't run)!

Comment: IT WORKS!! you are a genius, thank you SO much for your help! I´m so happy!
May I ask something more? if it´s not abusing of your generosity.

I was able to move the navigation arrows for the images adding the CSS they give here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xh3B2/

Now I just have left to remove the white border supposedly using this: http://jsfiddle.net/nJfAZ/

I have 0 idea of Java as you can see, do you know where I should place this in order to work? Hope it doesn´t remove the arrows.
If you tell me I will be able to figure out in the future if I want to change something else.

Comment: Hmm, not sure I understand what you're trying to do... Are you adding navigation arrows to navigate between photo posts or between photos of a photoset? And what white border are you referring to? Around the pictures or the arrows?

Comment: The white border around the pictures, sorry I wasn´t clear jaja the arrows are just fine, I just need to place that java script to remove white border around content: http://jsfiddle.net/nJfAZ/
By default, Fancybox adds a white border on images, etc and adding that piece of Java should remove it, but I don´t know where to place it!

Comment: Ok! You should learn some Javascript (and not Java, they're really not the same thing) and then jQuery (a "way" of doing Javascript if you will) because for Tumblr theming it's just awesome. Basically what the script is doing is getting all elements you've marked as "fancybox" and remove their padding in CSS. And as to where to put it, fancybox (thanks to jQuery) makes it very easy for you : just replace `$(".fancybox").fancybox();` with `$(".fancybox").fancybox({padding : 0});` in step 4.

Comment: That worked, thank you SO much for all your help, I truly appreciate it! and yes, I should really learn javascript, it would make things easier :)

Comment: Glad it worked! Thanks for accepting the answer! And if you enjoy photography blogs, feel free to follow my own photography sideblog : http://435nm.tumblr.com

Comment: Already following it, the blog is amazing! love the photos :)
Thank you again!